# Python - Unicode Converter

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, converters, unicode-string

i am looking for simple way how to convert decimal unicode to string.

For example:

I need convert number 76 to symbol "L".
I need something like this page does: https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chr` function is what you are looking for on Python3, `unichr` on Python2.

```
>>> u''.join(unichr(x) for x in [77,65,82,75])
u'MARK'
```

Comment: God bless you mate, tahnk you very much :)